# Consultar los clientes que solamente compraron en un año especifico

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas, distinct, consultar

tengo una tabla llamada VENTAS con los siguientes registros (es una parte hay mas de 1000 registros ahi):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy queriendo contar cuantos clientes compraron solamente en el año 2020, es decir, que no compraron nada en años anteriores ni futuros

Por ejemplo

| idCliente | AñoCompra |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 |
| 1 | 2020 |
| 1 | 2020 |
| 2 | 2020 |
| 2 | 2020 |
| 3 | 2019 |
| 4 | 2020 |
| 5 | 2019 |
| 5 | 2020 |
| 5 | 2021 |

La consulta sólo debe contar los idCliente (2,4) y darme como resultado que 2 clientes solamente compraron en el 2020

Estaba haciendo el siguiente código

```
select idCliente,count(distinct year(Fecha)=2020)=1 from venta group by idCliente;
```

Pero ese me trae también los clientes que solamente compraron en el 2019 y eso no es lo que quiero.

Si me pudieran ayudar les agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener sólo los clientes que compraron en `2020` puedes valerte de una sub-consulta que encuentre aquellos clientes que compraron en cualquier otro año y luego haces un `LEFT JOIN` con esa consulta, agregando un criterio `WHERE` que busque los `idCliente` nulos (esos serán los que no habrán comprado en otro año que no sea `2020`).

Algo así:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(v.idCliente)) AS total
FROM venta AS v
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        idCliente
    FROM venta AS tmp 
    WHERE 
        YEAR(tmp.fecha)<>2020 
    GROUP BY 
        idCliente 
) AS tmp
    ON v.idCliente = tmp.idCliente
WHERE  
    tmp.idCliente IS NULL AND 
    YEAR(v.fecha)=2020;
```

Aquí te dejo un fiddle. Se agradece uno cuando plantees preguntas relativas a la base de datos:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE venta (
  idCliente INT,
  fecha DATE
);
INSERT INTO venta (idCliente,fecha) VALUES (1,'2020-01-01');
INSERT INTO venta (idCliente,fecha) VALUES (1,'2021-01-01');
INSERT INTO venta (idCliente,fecha) VALUES (1,'2020-01-01');
INSERT INTO venta (idCliente,fecha) VALUES (2,'2020-01-01');
INSERT INTO venta (idCliente,fecha) VALUES (3,'2019-01-01');
INSERT INTO venta (idCliente,fecha) VALUES (2,'2020-01-01');
INSERT INTO venta (idCliente,fecha) VALUES (4,'2020-01-01');
INSERT INTO venta (idCliente,fecha) VALUES (4,'2020-01-01');
INSERT INTO venta (idCliente,fecha) VALUES (4,'2020-01-01');
INSERT INTO venta (idCliente,fecha) VALUES (3,'2020-01-01');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(v.idCliente)) AS total
FROM venta AS v
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        idCliente
    FROM venta AS tmp 
    WHERE 
        YEAR(tmp.fecha)<>2020 
    GROUP BY 
        idCliente 
) AS tmp
    ON v.idCliente = tmp.idCliente
WHERE  
    tmp.idCliente IS NULL AND 
    YEAR(v.fecha)=2020;
```

| total |
| --- |
| 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5NXEQgVUrWLMKRkeRtAXDX/1)

Comment: Gracias, pero en realidad no es consultar todas las ventas que se hizo en el 2020, en realidad es contar cuantos clientes unicamente compraron en el 2020 y no en otro año.

Comment: @WalterRivarola ohhhh pues eso no quedaba claro de entrada, o al menos no lo entendí así. Dame un momento y modifico la respuesta.

Comment: @WalterRivarola revisa la respuesta editada.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, pero al intentar probar me muestra el siguiente error

"Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function"

Cual sería el motivo de eso?

Comment: @WalterRivarola no debería dar ese error. ¿Podrías colocar al final de la pregunta la consulta que estás ejecutando?

Comment: ya he podido hacerlo correr, solamente necesitaba sacar la parte `HAVING COUNT(tmpTotal) > 0` y ahí ya me ha tirado 2 clientes como me mostraste

Comment: Tienes razón @WalterRivarola, el `HAVING` sobra en la sub-consulta. He actualizado la respuesta. Saludos y me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto.